# how do i insert the same string to every element in a python list after a given n number of characters

Tags: python, python-re

i have the following list:

```
List1=["181-CODE","187-CODE","1951-CODE"]
string="available"
```

i want to be able to insert the string "available" after the first 2 characters in every element of the List1 list, the answers i have found over the internet focus on either inserting the text in the beginning or in the end of each elemment

i tried this one.

```
import re
import time
List1=["181-CODE","187-CODE","1951-CODE"]
List2=[]
for x in range (3):
    x=List1[0]
    x1="available".join(re.findall("..",x))
    List2.append(x1)
    time.sleep(1)
    del List1[0]
```

Comment: `List2 = [i[:2] + 'available' + i[2:] for i in List1]`…?

Answer (score 0):

I'd slice for this ([How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works))

You may want to take some care to handle entries with less than 3 characters

- is the presence of one an error from the caller?
- should a single character have *another* added? like `a` -> `a_available`

```py
list1 = ["181-CODE","187-CODE","1951-CODE"]
results = []

for value in list1:
    if len(value) > 3:  # modify as-needed to manage length 0, 1, 2
        value = value[:2] + "available" + value[2:]
    results.append(value)
```